# SQL: Search a cell with a list of words from a second table

Tags: sql, string, compare

I have two tables in a data base.

TableA looks like this:

| description | value |
| --- | --- |
| yellow round | 10 |
| red squared | 20 |

TableB:

| ball | colored |
| --- | --- |
| round | red |
| circular | blue |
| globular | yellow |

Now I want to check if the cells in column 'description' contain any words from the columns 'ball' or 'colored' in TableB and add the result in an additional column.

The final table should look like this:

| description | value | ball | colored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yellow round | 10 | true | yes |
| red squared | 20 | false | yes |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem you are facing with doing this? It would be better to [include an MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you have tried and what the specific problem you face is. It would also help if the dataframes were included in code rather than as images.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: I'm using Google BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple `case` and `exists` is all you need

```
select *,
case when exists (select * from tableb b where a.description like concat('%',b.ball,'%') then 'true' else 'false' end as ball,
case when exists (select * from tableb b where a.description like concat('%',b.colored,'%') then 'Yes' else 'No' end as colored
from tablea a
```

Comment: Sound like a resonable solution but i'm getting this error in BigQuery:
'no matching signature for operator + for argument types: string, string.'

Comment: @yellingatclouds  `BigQuery` doesn't support concatenation with `+` however it has a `concat` function - I have amended.

Comment: Thanks Stu! This issue is solved. Now comes the next error:
"LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of 
fields from both sides of the join."
According to my understanding, this should not be a left join, since there is no join key.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have attached two queries. If you just to know whether the description column contains anything form ball or colored columns then please use query#2.

But if you only want to select rows from TableA if description column contains anything from ball or colored column then use query#1.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table tableA(description    varchar(50),value int);
 
 insert into tableA values ('yellow round', 10);
 insert into tableA values ('red squared', 20);
 
 create table TableB (ball varchar(50),colored varchar(50));
 insert into TableB values('round','red');
 insert into TableB values('circular','blue');
 insert into TableB values('globular','yellow');
```

Query#1:

```
 select description,value, max(ball)ball,max(colored)colored
 from 
 (
     select  a.*,(case when a.description like '%'+b.ball+'%' then 'true' else 'false' end) ball,
     (case when a.description like '%'+b.colored+'%' then 'yes' else 'no' end) colored
     from tableA a 
     inner join TableB b on a.description like '%'+b.ball+'%' or a.description like '%'+b.colored+'%'
 )t
 group by  description,value
```

Output:

| description | value | ball | colored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yellow round | 10 | true | yes |
| red squared | 20 | false | yes |

Query#2:

```
     select  a.*,
     Coalesce((select 'true' from TableB b where a.description like '%'+b.ball+'%'),'false') ball,
     Coalesce((select 'yes' from TableB b where a.description like '%'+b.colored+'%'),'no') colored
     from tableA a
```

Output:

| description | value | ball | colored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yellow round | 10 | true | yes |
| red squared | 20 | false | yes |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=69d30c91d4174993ed028207ee3dd05f)*

Comment: Sound like a resonable solution but i'm getting this error in BigQuery:
'no matching signature for operator + for argument types: string, string.'